# Explicit Solution $ \frac{\cos (x)-k}{\cos (y) +k}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is $y$ in the equation below? $k$ is a constant.

$$ \frac{\cos (x)-k}{\cos (y) +k}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} $$

---

This looks like a nice, symmetrical formula, but I've tried several methods to no avail, including WolframAlpha/Mathematica and algebraic simplification. Here's the farthest I could get:
$$\sin y \cos x - k \sin y = \sin x \cos y + k\sin x$$
$$\sin y \cos x - \sin x \cos y=k(\sin x + \sin y)$$
$$ \sin(y-x) = k(\sin x + \sin y)$$

I'd appreciate any suggestions for how to solve for $y$ and obtain an exact, analytic solution.

Comment: You can rearrange into $\frac a{\cos(y)+k}=\frac b{\sin(y)}\iff \frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)+k}=\frac ba$

Comment: @TymaGaidash Indeed, that gets me tantalizingly close, but not quite to solving for $y$.

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that a "solution" of the type $y=\text{something}$ should exist (right-hand side being a "formula" in $k$ and $x$), using standard notation and wellknown functions? Lots of equations cannot be solved in that way.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Indeed I do. This equation is the result of a physical phenomena which I cannot delve into the details of here. It agrees numerically with a another well-known equation. Thus, I have reason to believe that there is an exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution:
$$ \sin(y-x) = k(\sin x + \sin y)=2k \sin \frac{x+y}{2}\cos \frac{y-x}{2} $$
$$ 2\sin \frac{y-x}{2}\cos \frac{y-x}{2} - 2k \sin \frac{x+y}{2}\cos \frac{y-x}{2} =0$$
$$ 2\cos \frac{y-x}{2}(\sin \frac{y-x}{2} - k \sin \frac{x+y}{2}) =0$$

The first part,  $\cos \frac{y-x}{2}=0$ is easy, $y=x+\pi(2n+1)$.

The second part:
$$\sin \frac{y-x}{2} - k \sin \frac{x+y}{2}=0$$
$$\sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}-\cos \frac{y}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2}-k\sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}-k\cos \frac{y}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2}=0$$
$$(k-1)\sin \frac{y}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}+(k+1)\cos \frac{y}{2} \sin \frac{x}{2}=0$$
$$(k-1)\tan \frac{y}{2} +(k+1)\tan \frac{x}{2}=0$$ Now you can express $y$ in terms of $x$ using $\arctan$.

Comment: Hello Vasili. This exactly matches (numerically) with my original formula. I would like to acknowledge your simplification. If you would like to be acknowledged in my manuscript, please let me know.

Comment: @rb3652: Glad you found my answer useful and thanks for the proposition to be acknowledged.

Comment: OK. If indeed you would like to be acknowledged, please provide me of your name and email address and you will be notified when the manuscript is submitted for peer review and publication.

Answer (score 1):

Rearrange into:

$$\frac a{\cos(y)+k}=\frac b{\sin(y)}\iff\frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)+k}=\frac ba=c$$

Substitute $\cos(y)=t,\sin^2(y)=1-t^2$:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{k+t}=c\iff1-t^2=c^2(t+k)^2\iff (c^2+1) t^2+2kc^2t+k^2c^2-1=0$$

Applying the quadratic formula finally gives:

$$y=2\pi n\pm\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{c^2k\pm\sqrt{c^2(1-k^2)+1}}{c^2+1}\right),n\in\Bbb Z,c=\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)-k}$$

Comment: To clarify, $c=\frac{\sin x}{\cos (x) -k}$?

Answer (score 0):

> $$ \frac{\cos (x)-k}{\cos (y) +k}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} $$

If you just want to solve for $y$, then we just square it

$$\sin^2y(\cos(x)-k)^2=\sin^2x(\cos(y)+k)^2$$

then use the identity $\sin^2y=1-\cos^2y$

$$(1-\cos^2y)(\cos x-k)^2=\sin^2x(\cos(y)+k)^2$$

Now you get a quadratic equation with respect to $\cos y$ and you can proceed to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [tangent half-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) with $t=\tan \frac x2$ and $s=\frac y2$ we obtain

$$\frac{\cos (x)-k}{\cos (y) +k}=\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} \iff \frac{\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-k}{\frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2}+k}=\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{\frac{2s}{1+s^2}} \iff \frac{(st+1)((k-1)s+(k+1)t)}{s((k-1)s^2+k+1)}=0$$

which leads to

- $st+1=0 \iff \tan \frac x2\tan \frac y2=-1$
- $(k-1)s+(k+1)t=0\iff (k+1)\tan \frac x2+(k-1)\tan \frac y2=0$